# How to turn off org-agenda-log-mode once activated?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, logging

The description of the function *org-agenda-log-mode* is

> Toggle log mode in an agenda buffer.

I remember it working like that, the short cut 'l' working like an on/off switch.

Currently on my system, the function (and the shortcut) is always turning it on, and the only way to turn the log-mode of the agenda off (if I mistakenly activate it) is to restart emacs, which is kind of annoying.

I am using the following versions of Emacs and Orgmode:

> GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.24, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2023-02-23, modified by Debian
> Org mode version 9.3 (release_9.3 @ /usr/share/emacs/27.1/lisp/org/)

Comment: `l` toggles it for me: I get a message in the echo area `Log mode is on/off`  plus an indicator in the mode line of the agenda buffer: `Log` is shown when on, it is not when off.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with Org 9.3 either: it works as documented. What does `C-h c l` say in the agenda buffer? Can you reproduce it if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, something in your init file(s) is causing it.